# How to show only class name when running unit tests from gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea, junit5

For IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition v2020.3.1

When I run a test from a Gradle project, the full name of the class is displayed. But this does not happen when I run the same type of test in a Maven project. It's a bit annoying because it's not easy to read when you run multiple unit tests.

Maven & Gradle projects on IntelliJ IDEA screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hide/disable grouping by packaged for Gradle. Feel free to file a request for this at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.